# Aquatic chemistry, pH and alkalinity

Tags: acid-base, ph

Hope you can help me with an aquatic chemistry question.
I have different types of water of different pH and alkalinity.
pH, alkalinity, HCO3 and CO2 concentrations are known.
I need to calculate the resulting pH from mixing the different water sources together (assuming equal fractions, and complete mixing). I am struggling with how to tackle this, because of the role of alkalinity.

To keep a good overview, let's use two of the sample water sources:

- A) pH: 4,9, CO2: 73 umol/L, HCO3: 2 umol/L, alkalinity: 0.13 meq/L
- B) pH: 8, CO2: 50 umol/L, HCO3: 1823 umol/L, alkalinity: 1.67 meq/L

My first guess would be to convert pH to [H+] and average those to get the new pH. But then I'm ignoring alkalinity, which is an important factor. Not sure how to incorporate that. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can get your hands on a copy of Water Chemistry by Snoeyink and Jenkins, you'll be able to work this out - hands-down the best book on the topic, IMO. You'll also need to know how you are expressing alkalinity, i.e., as $\ce{HCO_{3}^{-}}$ or $\ce{CaCO3}$. Chapters 4 and 6 are particularly relevant and walk through the mass balance and other equations. If you're interested in learning how a lot of aquatic chemists do it, download [PHREEQC](https://www.usgs.gov/software/phreeqc-version-3) and go from there.